# regex matching special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find matching special characters.
How can I define my pattern for this?
( ) , [ ] , { }

here's my code thus far..
I plan on calling the regexChecker() in the matchSpecChars()
Then matchSpecChars() in the main.

regexChecker("(______)", input);   <--- pattern ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class VictorSolutions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

    public static void matchSpecChars() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter characters: ");
        input.next();

    }

    public static void regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check) {

        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);

        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);

        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(regexMatcher.group().trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define my pattern for this? ( ) , [ ] , { }

```
String theRegex = "^(?:\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{})$";
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a literal character which has special meaning in regexes, you need to escape it. For example, to match a literal `.`, your regex would be `\.`; so `\.\*` would match exactly two characters: a dot followed by an asterisk.

Your pattern might be something like: `regexChecker\(\"\(______\)\", input\); \<\-\-\- pattern \?`

Comment: Since he's using Java the backslashes have to be escaped in string literals, so to find a literal `.` he would need `\\.`.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use the regex:

```
[]()\[{}]
```

The regex as escaped string:

```
"[]()\\[{}]"
```

---

There are also Unicode categories for open and close punctuation.

```
[\p{Ps}\p{Pe}]
```

The regex as escaped string:

```
"[\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}]"
```